# Expected value of c.d.f when normal distributed

Tags: statistics, integration, probability-theory

I need help to calculate the expected value of an invertal of a c.d.f function which is normal distributed. I know that
$E(X)=\int^\infty_0 (1-F(x))dx$

What i need is to calculate 
$E(w|w \geq R)=\int^\infty_R (1-\Phi(w))dw$
Where $\Phi(w)$ is the c.d.f of the general normal distrubtion

I hope you can help.
- Morten

Comment: You might mean $E(w;w\gt R)$ instead of $E(w\mid w\gt R)$.

Comment: Would you like to know whether this formula is correct and how to show this, or rather you are interested in finding the value of this expectation in case of normal distribution?

Comment: I of cause mean E(w;w>r) not conditional on it. I would like to know how to calcualted the value. I am almost certain that the equation is correct, but when I try to calculated it with the c.d.f of a normal distribution, then I am stuck.

Comment: @Morten where does the first formula come from?

Answer (score 4):

There are some undigested results here... so let us try to straighten the question by going back to the basics. One is given a real valued random variable $X$ with CDF $F$, and, for some real number $R$, one considers
$$
G(R)=\int_R^{+\infty}(1-F(x))\,\mathrm dx=\int_R^{+\infty}\mathbb P(X\gt x)\,\mathrm dx.
$$
For every real number $\xi$, considering separately the cases $\xi\gt R$ and $\xi\leqslant R$, one sees that
$$
\int_R^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{\xi\gt x}\,\mathrm dx=(\xi-R)^+.
$$
Integrating this identity with respect to the distribution of $X$ yields
$$
G(R)=\mathbb E((X-R)^+)=\mathbb E(X-R;X\gt R).
$$
Now to the applications:

- For $R=0$, $G(0)=\mathbb E(X;X\gt0)$ hence $G(0)=\mathbb E(X)$ (your first statement) if and only if $X\geqslant0$ almost surely.
- In general, $G(R)=\mathbb E(X;X\gt R)$ (your second statement) if and only if $R\cdot\mathbb P(X\gt R)=0$, that is, either $R=0$ or $X\leqslant R$ almost surely. One would rather use
  $$
  \mathbb E(X;X\gt R)=R\cdot\mathbb P(X\gt R)+G(R)=R\cdot(1-F(R))+\int_R^{+\infty}(1-F(x))\,\mathrm dx.
  $$